# How to rotate a UILabel inside a UICollectionViewCell considering performance?

Tags: ios, performance, reusability, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an `UICollectionView` where I am reusing many `UICollectionViewCells` with product information, think of Pinterest.

But it comes to a point where I have a price tag and would like to rotate the price ribbon about 45 degrees for everyone of the cells.

[image: please note the green price ribbon]

What would be the best performance wise method to achieve that?

I have tried with:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ItemCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *price;

@end


@implementation ItemCollectionViewCell

@synthesize price;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    price.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_4, 0, 0, 1);
    price.layer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(price.transform, 25, -15, 0);
    price.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}

@end
```

But the overall result as scrolling and pushing new views into the navigation controller is really slow.

### Update

- It seems that iOS6 Autolayout is the main cause for the performance decrease, but I still don't know how to fix this or remove autolayout only for the price label.

Comment: Have you time profiled the app to see where the time is being spent. I suspect it isn't with rotating the label.

Comment: I didn't profiled it yet, but it all becomes really fast as soon as I remove the transformation methods from the code.

Comment: Fogmeister: I just figured out that when deactivating iOS6 Autolayout on the main Storyboard it all goes bananas. It is certainly having trouble to rotate and keep its crazy logic at the same time. Any idea how to solve or deactivate AutoLayout only for the price label instead? cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me was to remove the attributes defined by iOS6 autoLayout feature inside the `UICollectionViewCell` where it sets constraints for the `price` label, being:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    NSMutableArray* cons = [NSMutableArray array];
    //iterating through UICollectionViewCell constraint list
    for (NSLayoutConstraint* con in self.constraints) {
        //if the target constraint is `price` then add that to the array
        if (con.firstItem == price || con.secondItem == price) {
            [cons addObject:con];
        }
    }
    //remove the unwanted constraints array to the UICollectionViewCell
    [self removeConstraints:cons];

    //ready to roll…
    price.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_4, 0, 0, 1);
    price.layer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(price.transform, 25, -15, 0);
    price.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}
```